# Cutting raster using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, editing

I would like to cut a raster file that I have.

Here I attach a example of how it is original:

[image]

And this is how I would like it would be. (I have cut the image on Paint):

[image]

Can someone give me a hint on how can it be done? Is it simple like a "select" and delete?

Comment: Use Clip data management, use clipping geometry of polygon

Comment: you asked a similar question [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188807/cut-only-a-river-of-a-raster-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, use graphics from the Draw toolbar and use the polygon to draw what you want.
2. Then right click on the Layers on the TOC.
3. Scroll down to Convert Graphics to Features...
4. Save your new polygon as a Area of Interest or whatever you like to name it.
5. Use Extract by Mask under Spatial Analyst Tools --> Extraction.